# image swap doesnt return to original image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mouseover, jquery-hover

I had a javscript image swap that would without problem swap an image on hover. I implemented highslide.js and now the bottom image will not return to it's original image on mouse out.

Any suggestions?

my scripts are as follows

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jwbox.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="highslide/highslide-with-gallery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="highslide/highslide.config.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

and my html

```
<a id="gallery-opener" href="javascript:;" onclick="document.getElementById('thumb1').onclick()" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('lodge','','Images/river_over.png',1)">
            <img src="Images/river_up.png" name="lodge" width="340" height="167" border="0" id="lodge" /></a> 

        <a id="gallery-opener" href="javascript:;" onclick="document.getElementById('thumb2').onclick()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('catch','','Images/catch_over.png',1)">
        <img src="Images/catch_up.png" name="catch" width="340" height="167" border="0" id="catch" /></a>
```

you can see an example here
http://www.flyfishinggreyriver.com/index2.html

thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You must have removed the `onmouseout` attribute from that image's parent  at some point.

Adding `onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()"` to the parent `<a>` of the last image allows it to restore.

---

Just so you know, you can use CSS for image rollover transitions, which is a lot easier than JavaScript.
You've also got multiple items with the same ID, which should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()"` event for the bottom image `<a>` tag. Include that and everything will work fine.